# Spring for browser and web service

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I'm gonna make a project that have `AngularJS` with `Spring`.

The `Spring` layer needs to be a `WebService` layer too, but the services in `Spring WebServices` and `SpringMVC` are the same.

The question is:

Should I make 2 layers with SpringMVC(MVC will call WS) and WS **or** make everything in the same layer?

If 2 layers, how can I call WS through MVC(Controllers)

**Edit for add some samples:**

AngularJS call {myURL}/cars/list through Cars page {myURL/cars}

WS just call {myURL}/cars/list

The doubt is provide the page for AngularJS with an architecture that provides services for both (AngularJS and WS calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the your approach may be: implements the business logic in a service layer, in your spring bean or `@Service` bean let say, then you should create an "endpoint" layer that using the your service previously implemented, expose them as web service soap in a set of endpoint and as rest ws for your angularJS application part. In this way in your restController(rest part) and enpointPart(SpringWS) you can benefit of the same business logic but you can use the same logic in the two usage way.

Consider that SpringWS (when you talk about Spring WebService I assume that you are talking of SpringWS that impelments the WebService tecnology in Spring) you have register the DispatcherMessageServlet and this fornt controller servlet will be under a different url mapping respect to the DispatcherServlet.

even better you may do a thinks like this:

1. /app-context/your-html-pageurl for your html in your presentation
   layer
2. /app-context/api/your-rest-api-url for the your @RestController
3. /app-context/service/* for your ws (soap in this case) layer

I hope that this can be usefull for you and that I understanded well the your question.

Comment: I was searching here and I saw the approach: create spring controllers just to provide html pages and rest controller separated. So would an html layer and rest layer, with differentes urls. e.g: myurl/system/cars & myurl/api/cars/list

Comment: yes this is a good choice i just edit the my ansuare for underline this